# What are the best method for presenting demographic data?

Tags: demography, presentation

I have a large dataset of people, and connected demographic data, like age, gender and place of residence.

I want to present a typical person from this dataset, as a presentation technique.

Should I use average, median or any other technique? What is the best way to find the most "typical" demographic data?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the purpose of your presentaton.  The purpose determines the "best" way to present the data, and how you should define "typical".

Generally, for numerical variables, median is better than average. For categorical variables like gender, unless vast majority (say, >75%) is in one category, you might want to say something like "60% of our customers are males, 40% are females", or "70% are white, 20% are black, 10% are other races".  But you can say "our typical customer is American" if 90% are Americans.